# How our thoughts influence others -- seeking source from Lekutei Maharan

Tags: tefilla, bein-adam-lachavero, kavana-intent, breslov, thought

I once came across a quote from Likutei Maharan (or maybe the back section, Likutei Tanina) that spelled out very clearly that, when we have positive thoughts towards other people, no matter how far away they may be from us, it affects their thoughts and causes them to likewise think positively towards us.

I've been looking to find it again. I have no idea where it is or how I even found it in the first place.

If you know what I'm talking about and where it is, I'd appreciate knowing the exact source.

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you're thinking of the LM #282 someone posted below, where your favorable judgement giving someone the benefit of the doubt by finding one good point transforms him even a rasha into not rasha? It says this will cause them to make teshuvah but doesn't say or at least spell out that they're gonna come around and think and do nice of you. So I don't think that premise you stated is actually true though it sounds nice, but I might be wrong.

Comment: Even many verses lament of being rewarded evil for good [action - all the more so with thought?] Ps. 35:12-13 "They rewarded me evil for good to the spoiling of my soul. But as for me, when they were sick, my clothing was sackcloth: I humbled my soul with fasting; and my prayer returned into mine own bosom..." and Ps. 109:5 "And they have rewarded me evil for good, and hatred for my love."  Also this sounds more like the foreign philosophy of the Law of Attraction or "Thinking good will bring you good."

Answer (score 1):

The source is Likutay Moharan 282:

*"Know, a person must judge everyone favorably (Avot 1:6). Even someone who is completely wicked, it is necessary to search and find in him some modicum of good; that in that little bit he is not wicked. And by finding in him a modicum of good and judging him favorably, one genuinely elevates him to the scale of merit and can bring him to repent."*